# mysql 'too long' exception not working in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, exception, pdo

```
public function edit($body){
    try
    {
     $stmt=$this->db->prepare("UPDATE news SET body=:body");
     $stmt->bindparam(":body",$body);
     $stmt->execute();
     return true; 
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    { 
      echo $e->getMessage();
      return false;
    }
  }
```

It always saving missed data when data too long for column 'body' I want to catch exception.

Comment: didn't understand your question properly. can you post the exact text of your error message?

Comment: You can enable `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES` and `STRICT_ALL_TABLES` in MySQL. it won't store truncated values, then it will rise exception on long values

Comment: OK, Thanks :D I'll try